# HP 2910 Port Security (send alarm SNMP)

Tags: switch, hp-procurve, port-security

I'm looking for correct "OID Value" when security port send alarm.
 I will see its in my SNMP logs.

---

**Edit:**

I forgot to mention, i already download this MIB but i didn't find the correct OID

Comment: Can't you test it, provoking the event, looking which OID is received and searching for it in the MIB?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

Check the [MIB](https://h10145.www1.hpe.com/Downloads/SoftwareReleases.aspx?ProductNumber=J9147A&lang=en&cc=us&prodSeriesId=3901671), it should be in there.

edit:

`findstr /i portsecurity *.mib` has hits in `hpicfFf.mib` and `hpicfFtrCo.mib`.